# Need help with notation for total derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, differential

consider the function

$$f = f(x(t),y(t))$$

I know that its total derivative wrt t is

$$\frac {df}{dt} = \frac {\partial f} {\partial x} \frac {dx}{dt} + \frac {\partial f}{\partial y} \frac {dy}{dt}$$

and that the total derivative wrt x is
$$ \frac {df} {dx} = \frac {\partial f} {\partial x} \frac {dx}{dx} + \frac {\partial f} {\partial y} \frac {dy} {dx}$$

However I am not fully familiar with the notation and the forms in which it takes during more extreme conditions, such as the following, could anyone fill the blanks in for me?

1)$$f = f(x(t,w),y(t,w))$$
$$\frac {df}{dt} = ?$$
2)
$$f = f(x(g(t,w)),y(g(t,w)))$$
$$\frac {df}{dt} = ?$$
3)
$$f = f(x(g(t,w),z),y(g(t,w),z))$$
$$\frac {df}{dt} = ?$$
4)
$$f = f(x(g(t)),y(g(t)))$$
$$\frac {df}{dt} = ?$$

how would I go about writing these properly? Any answer will help illustrate the semantics in much greater detail

Comment: 1. $$\frac{df}{dt}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial t}$$

as $f$ is a function of two variables ($x, y$) and $x, y$ are functions of two variables ($t, w$).

2. $$\frac{df}{dt}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{dx}{dg} \frac{\partial g}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{dy}{dg} \frac{\partial g}{\partial t}$$

as $f$ is a function of two variables, $x$ and $y$ are functions of a single variable ($g$) and $g$ is a function of two variables. From this, hopefully you can deduce the pattern.

Comment: maybe I am missing the point, but this beg the question **why I cant just express those two lines with exclusively partials?**

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial t}$$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial g} \frac{\partial g}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial g} \frac{\partial g}{\partial t}$$
I mean, they look awfully similar to just partial derivatives except with a d instead of $\partial$

Comment: You can express it the way you have it written (now, after you edited your comment / it just displayed properly on my computer). We just generally use $\partial$ as notation for the derivative of a function of _more than one variable_. See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1624376/solving-second-order-ode-using-an-integrating-factor#comment3312208_1624376) example from today where someone has used partial notation when the function is only of one variable $\eta$.

Comment: I replaced them with $\frac {\partial x} {\partial g}$ and $\frac {\partial y} {\partial g}$ respectively

I have yet to see a difference between total derivatives/partial derivatives besides semantics/esoteric details. e.g. use a d when functions of single variables and $\partial$ when multi variables.

but what can total derivatives DO? that partials cant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we suppose that $f(x,y)$ is differentiable, so by definition of the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ :
$$f(x+h,y) = f(x,y) + h \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x} + h \epsilon_1(h)$$
$$f(x,y+h) = f(x,y) + h \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y} + h \epsilon_2(h)$$
where $\epsilon_i(h)$ are residual functions such that $\lim_{h \to 0} \epsilon_i(h) = 0$

now if $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}$ are continuous, i.e. $f(x,y)$ is continuously differentiable :

$$f(x+h,y+C h) = f(x,y) + h \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x} + C h \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y} + h\epsilon(h)$$
(it is a good exercice to prove it)

finally, because we suppose that $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are differentiable : $x(t+h) = x(t) + h x'(t) + h\epsilon_3(h)$ and $y(t+h) = y(t) + h y'(t) + h\epsilon_4(h)$ hence :

$$f(x(t+h),y(t+h)) = f(x(t)+h x'(t),y(t)+h y'(t)) + h \epsilon_5(h)
= f(x(t),y(t)) + h x'(t) \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x} + h y'(t) \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y} + h \epsilon_6(h)$$

which proves that :

$$\frac{\partial f(x(t),y(t))}{\partial t} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x(t+h),y(t+h))-f(x(t),y(t))}{h} = x'(t) \frac{\partial f(x(t),y(t))}{\partial x} + y'(t) \frac{\partial f(x(t),y(t))}{\partial y}$$

now adapt all this to the simpler notations above, and to compute the nested derivatives of your first question.

Answer (score 1):

I shall write for the most extreme case (3)

$$\frac{df}{dt} =\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial g}\frac{dg}{dt}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial g}\frac{\partial g}{\partial w} \frac{dw}{dt}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial z}\frac{dz}{dt}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial g}\frac{dg}{dt}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial g}\frac{\partial g}{\partial w} \frac{dw}{dt}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial z}\frac{dz}{dt}$$

A good rule of thumb could be imagining this as an expanding tree.

Answer (score 0):

In general if you have the function $H(t)= F(G(t))$ and you want to find the derivative of $h$ with respect to $t$. You have the general rule: 
$$\frac{d H}{dt} = DF(G(t))(\frac{d G}{dt}).$$ It seems to be strange notation with respect to your level, but in this case you can take,for example, $$G(t)= (x(t),y(t))$$ and use $$Df((x,y))((z_1,z_2))= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}z_1+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}z_2.$$

Comment: could you provide a bit more insight on what is going on here? I am not a calculus wizard and fail to see a lot of the relation between the variables/equations you just posted. Im also really confused what DF(G(t)) is, do you mean dF(G(t)), like the differential df?